# How to process this captcha image for Tesseract?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, captcha

How would I make this kind of captcha readable by Tesseract using OpenCV?

[image]

I'm trying replacing background color to white. Then turn the image to gray scale. Finally, use threshold to make all characters to black. But still Tesseract can't detect a single character:

```js
captchaimg = cv2.imread("captcha.png")

captchaimg[np.where((captchaimg == [19, 20, 154]).all(axis=2))] = [
    255, 255, 255]

gry = cv2.cvtColor(captchaimg , cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gry = cv2.threshold(gry, 228, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

cv2.imwrite("result.png", gry)
```

Result:

[image]